# Identifying and Fixing Incorrect Double Slash URLs in PrestaShop 1.7.8

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I'm having an issue with PrestaShop concerning erroneous links. The problem was identified using Screaming Frog SEO Spider, which revealed the presence of links with a double slash (e.g., .pl//product-path), which as we know is an incorrect URL structure and can negatively impact SEO as well as site functionality.

Initially, I checked the .sql file that could contain these erroneous URLs, but the file analysis did not show the presence of such links. Then I searched the PrestaShop database using SQL queries, directing attention to tables that could potentially store page content, such as product descriptions, CMS content, and SEO configurations. I checked the pr_ets_seo_meta table and several other standard tables, especially the canonical_url, content_analysis, and social_desc columns, which could contain full URLs.  Unfortunately, the queries did not yield any results – no such links were found in any of these columns. This means that the problematic URLs are not directly recorded in the database or are generated dynamically by the site.

Could you suggest any other tables where I might look for these links? Is there a module or part of the code that could dynamically generate URLs on the site? Alternatively, do you have any experience in locating and solving similar issues in PrestaShop 1.7.8?